# error while parsing url using python

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I am working on a url using python.
If I click the url, I am able to get the excel file.
but If I run following code, it gives me weird output.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.urlopen('http://intranet.stats.gov.my/trade/download.php?id=4&var=2012/2012%20MALAYSIA%27S%20EXPORTS%20BY%20ECONOMIC%20GROUPING.xls').read()
```

output :

```
"<script language=javascript>window.location='2012/2012 MALAYSIA\\'S EXPORTS BY ECONOMIC GROUPING.xls'</script>"
```

why its not able to read content with urllib2?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look using an http listener (or even Google Chrome Developer Tools), there's a redirect using javascript when you get to the page.

You will need to access the initial url, parse the result and fetch again the actual url.

Answer (score 1):

@Kai in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8066106/1179026) seems to have found an answer to javascript redirects using the module `Selenium`

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
link = "http://yourlink.com"
driver.get(link)

#this waits for the new page to load
while(link == driver.current_url):
  time.sleep(1)

redirected_url = driver.current_url
```