# Why isn't my Python-based Selenium PhantomJS webcrawler reaching the web?

Tags: python, proxy, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, phantomjs

I'm trying to have this simple code reach the Internet. I'm behind a proxy server but I've set my http_proxy, https_proxy, and no_proxy environment variables.

Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
driver.page_source
```

Output:

```
u'<html><head><title> Web Authentication Redirect</title><meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=https://1.1.1.1/login.html?redirect=www.google.com/"></head><body>\n</body></html>'
```

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Also, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like something on your network loads itself and then instantly redirects you to where you wanted to go. I would think that you just need to follow the redirect before getting the page source.

see [Getting the final destination of a JavaScript redirect on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053295/getting-the-final-destination-of-a-javascript-redirect-on-a-website) for waiting until selemium has followed the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a page where you land on a page, and then it redirects you (aka, a waiting issue), then you could try `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Google"))`

Note: that is Java code, but it shouldn't be too hard to convert.  `wait` is an instance of `WebDriverWait`