# Is there a way to get the final destination of a wikipedia url?

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm currently trying to get the description page of a bird using its scientific name for any available language. For example, using the scientific name "Ibycter americanus" as endpoint to "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", the browser redirects me to [the english wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-throated_caracara). If I use the subdomain "fr", to get it in french, I am redirected [to the french page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caracara_%C3%A0_gorge_rouge).

This all works perfectly well in a browser, but I'm unable to get the final url in python code:

```
req = urllib2.Request("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + "Ibycter americanus")
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
finalurl = res.geturl()
print(finalurl)
```

The finalurl is always "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibycter_americanus", and not "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-throated_caracara" like it shows in the browser. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the URL actually *is* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibycter_americanus, and it's getting rewritten in the location bar by Javascript.

Comment: Is there a way to get that rewrite by running the javascript?

Comment: @user2357112 Yup. That's probably what it is. Look what it even says on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-throated_caracara) - _" (Redirected from [Ibycter americanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ibycter_americanus&redirect=no))"_.

Comment: @MichaelEilersSmith with JS : `document.getElementsByClassName('interlanguage-link interwiki-fr')[0].firstChild.href` gives you the french url

Comment: `urllib2` doesn't follow redirects, use other requests library or actual Wikipedia API.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it working using selenium and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053295/getting-the-final-destination-of-a-javascript-redirect-on-a-website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best use the API for something like this. E.g. [action=query&titles=Ibycter+americanus&redirects=1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&titles=Ibycter+americanus&redirects=1)

Comment: Wow. Really wish I'd known about the redirects parameter. Thanks!