# Is it okay to add 'www' to any domains?

Tags: python, web, pyqt

I modified a web scraping code from https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
from sys import argv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Use result of rendering.
class Render(QWebPage):
  def __init__(self, url):
    self.app = QApplication(argv)
    QWebPage.__init__(self)
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
    self.app.exec_()

  def _loadFinished(self, result):
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()
    self.app.quit()

r = Render(url)
result = unicode(r.frame.toHtml().toUtf8(), encoding="UTF-8")

soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')

for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()
text = soup.get_text().encode("utf-8")
```

With this code, I found that "nate.com" doesn't return any text, but "www.nate.com" does. So, I am trying to add "www" for all domains.

1. Are there some websites that I shouldn't add "www" to their domains?

(like this)

```
if "www" in url:
    url = url.split("www")[1]
url = "www" + url
```

2. (optional) Why "nate.com" doesn't return any texts but "www.nate.com" does? I found it redirects to "www.nate.com" with chrome.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: There's no way to know until you make the request and find out.  What any given web server returns for any given request is up to them.  As for your second question, it seems like "doesn't return any text" means it returns a redirect.  Perhaps you should add a feature to your code to follow redirects?

Comment: No, it is not safe to blindly add `www` to any domain. E.g. there's no such thing as www.mail.google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there some websites that I shouldn't add "www" to their domains?

Yes. For example `huji.ac.il`:

```
$ http http://huji.ac.il
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 94
Cache-Control: max-age=300
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 173
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 25 Aug 2017 01:16:23 GMT
Expires: Fri, 25 Aug 2017 01:19:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://new.huji.ac.il">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<a href="http://new.huji.ac.il">click here</a> jumping ....
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Ok, now lets try `www.huji.ac.il`:

```
$ http http://www.huji.ac.il
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=300
Connection: close
Content-Length: 173
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 25 Aug 2017 01:16:31 GMT
Expires: Fri, 25 Aug 2017 01:21:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://new.huji.ac.il">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<a href="http://new.huji.ac.il">click here</a> jumping ....
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

In any case it redirects to `new.huji.ac.il`, lets try it with `www`:

```
$ http http://www.new.huji.ac.il

http: error: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.new.huji.ac.il', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f54f57fdd90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)) while doing GET request to URL: http://www.new.huji.ac.il/
```

So `www` in this example caused to error.

> Why "nate.com" doesn't return any texts but "www.nate.com" does? I found it redirects to "www.nate.com" with chrome.

Because "nate.com" do redirection with JavaScript

```
$ http http://nate.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: ko
Content-Length: 88
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 25 Aug 2017 01:13:34 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding

<script type='text/javascript'>location.href='http://www.nate.com';</script>
```

---

As pointed in comments: you should add a feature to your code to follow redirects.

Comment: Do you know why people use JavaScript redirect instead of regular redirection? FYI: [Get Redirect URL with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053295/getting-the-final-destination-of-a-javascript-redirect-on-a-website)

Comment: I'm not sure, probably its a legacy.